# Laravel authentication via Passport using "Authorization Code Grant with PKCE" for stateless application

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, stateless, pkce

I am developing stateless API service with authentication by JWT tokens, service must have access token and refresh token, for implementation used official **Laravel Passport** package.

The **Laravel Passport** package documentation ([Laravel Passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#password-grant-tokens)) states that **Password Grant Tokens** are deprecated:
[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8brf6.png)

If you go to [OAuth 2.0 Server documentation](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/which-grant/) - it will say that **Password Grant** is really deprecated and it is recommended to use it instead **Authorization code grant**:
[proof 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjtMd.png)
[proof 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFDXv.png)

In the documentation for the **Authorization code grant** [Authorization code grant documentation](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/which-grant/)

The documentation for the channel shows two parts of the implementation:

1. In the first part of the implementation, I have to send a request to get the code and state.
2. In the second part of the implementation, using the code (which came in the first part), we get tokens.
3. The first problem is that the documentation in the first part should be redirecting, but since I have a stateless service, I can't use redirects.
4. The second problem is that the package uses a web provider (StatefulGuard) for this, but since stateless applications it only has an api provider (TokenGuard).

[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waOQz.png)

Comment: Are you planning for your app to provide auth services to other apps, become some sort of identity provider or to implement authentication with a third party such as google, facebook, etc. ? Maybe just using Laravel Breeze is enough for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but breezy won't work for my service. I need oauth support, specifically to simply authenticate users with an access token and a refresh token.

Comment: Well oauth is much more than that, if you only need access token and refresh token it may be achieved with breeze, access token has a short TTL while refresh token are long lived, when you issue a refresh token it means client can re authenticate with refresh token instead of doing the complete login/Auth process, so you check for access token if this is not valid or expired you check for refresh token if valid you issue a new access token, de must be aware of the process.